# Targeting a single device with Firebase notifications (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Could somebody please tell me a way to target one single device to send a push notification through Firebase on iOS? And also, is it possible to send a push notification to a single device with the user's phone number or username or other information (possibly with a database)? I've searched everywhere but to no avail. I'd really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

in firebase

```
click Grow to expand it -> Notifications-> New message
```

[image]

select single device , paste [your FCM token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#access_the_registration_token) for that user and enter any more data you want , then click send message

Comment: How do I find out the token of that specific user. For example, I want to send notifications to a person who has purchased a certain product (like a discount coupon). However, how do I know the token of that user? Thanks

Comment: you should Read here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options